# Remote Notification not adding in iPhone Notification Center in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, apple-push-notifications

My notification working when app is Active.

I have enable background mode 1.Background Fetch. 2. Remote Notification
App Delegate look like

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
//rest of code

  completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

Also, Paylaod look like

```
{     
   aps={ "content-available"=1; 
   message="asdf"  
}; 

 }
```

Notification in app state as follows

> Active= Working
>
> Background= Received but not added in notification center i need to
>   manually click on app.(I can't see it in device notification center)
>
> Closed: Not working (Expected to add in Notification center).

I tested by re-starting device,
What could be the issue?

Is it due to absence of "alert","sound" in payload?

Comment: payload in not correct. it must contain a `alert` key with message string as `value` or custom payload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need an `alert` value, otherwise there's nothing to display in the Notification Center.

[The Remote Notification Payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW1)

Comment: Well it was working with Parse. but now Integrated AWS and found this issue.